# R - new variables from two subsets in data frame, random order in rows

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame containing two sets of variables: First, 30 columns containing 30 stimulus IDs, but in random order for each row. Then, the 30 response values relative to each stimulus. The first column of each block consist of a stimulus-response pair, the second column from each block are the second stimulus response pair etc., but the stimulus id itself varies.

I want to create new variables for each stimulus ID with the corresponding response.
I believe what I have is similar to the end-result of this question: [Shuffle a data frame while maintaining order with another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584310/shuffle-a-data-frame-while-maintaining-order-with-another-data-frame)

Example:

```
set.seed(3)
d <- data.frame( a = c("L", "G", "E", "E"), 
                 b = c("G", "E", "L", "G"), 
                 c = c("E", "L", "G", "L"), 
                 e = rnorm(4), f = rnorm(4), g = rnorm(4))
d
#   a b c          e          f          g
# 1 L G E -1.1312186 -0.3076564  0.1998116
# 2 G E L -0.7163585 -0.9530173 -0.5784837
# 3 E L G  0.2526524 -0.6482428 -0.9423007
# 4 E G L  0.1520457  1.2243136 -0.2037282
```

Output I want:

```
d$L <- c(d[1, 4], d[2, 6], d[3, 5], d[4, 6])
d$E <- c(d[1, 6], d[2, 5], d[3, 4], d[4, 4])
d$G <- c(d[1, 5], d[2, 4], d[3, 6], d[4, 5])
d
#   a b c          e          f          g          L          E
# 1 L G E -1.1312186 -0.3076564  0.1998116 -1.1312186  0.1998116
# 2 G E L -0.7163585 -0.9530173 -0.5784837 -0.5784837 -0.9530173
# 3 E L G  0.2526524 -0.6482428 -0.9423007 -0.6482428  0.2526524
# 4 E G L  0.1520457  1.2243136 -0.2037282 -0.9423007 -1.1312186
```

I have two problems:

1. populating the new stimulus variable
2. repeating this for each stimulus

for 1., I tried nested ifelse statements

```
d$L <- ifelse(d$a == "L", d$e,
              ifelse(d$b=="L", d$f,
                     ifelse(d$c=="L", d$g, NA)))
```

but the last `ifelse` overrides the first two. I tried a `dplyr::mutate` but can't figure out how to have one single `ifelse` statement, and with case_when got stuck on how to reference the correct column in the second set containing the response, and not defaulting to the first response column.

For 2.: I think I am supposed to use `mapply` with the two subsets divided in two separate matrices, but as far as I know, I then need a function-based solution for my first problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a row/column index to extract the values from columns 4:6 and assign it to three new columns in the dataset

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(d[1:3]))
d[un1] <- lapply(un1, function(x) 
         d[4:6][cbind(seq_len(nrow(d)), max.col(d[1:3] == x, "first"))])
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(a = c("L", "G", "E", "E"), b = c("G", "E", "L", 
"G"), c = c("E", "L", "G", "L"), e = c(-1.1312186, -0.7163585, 
0.2526524, 0.1520457), f = c(-0.3076564, -0.9530173, -0.6482428, 
1.2243136), g = c(0.1998116, -0.5784837, -0.9423007, -0.2037282
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```